# How to disable x paste in emacs

Tags: emacs, paste

Every single time I highlight something in emacs, it copies it. Is there any way to disable this annoying behavior? Im on ubuntu.

Comment: I'm surprised if all your other X applications don't do this as well (it's very standard behaviour).

Comment: I'd be curious to know why you don't like this behavior: I find it one of those hidden niceties of X.

Comment: when im copying something and accidently highlight something in my emacs browser, its annoying for something to be pushed onto the copy ring or whatever. alt w is quick enough for me that highlighting is not really necessary for emacs!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This setting should disable it:

```
(setq mouse-drag-copy-region nil)
```

Documentation for the variable is:

> Documentation: If non-nil, mouse drag
>   copies region to kill-ring.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for all applications and not just emacs?

Comment: I know I'm late for the party, but @Drooling_Sheep: check out and possibly remove any clipboard handler your DE might be stuffing down your throat. You'll get X selection and X clipboard registers then separately. Those two are probably blended by the handler.